# Access dictionary fields by a conditional key

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a class in python with plenty of methods that access multiple fields of a dictionary like this:

```
{
    "a": {
        "element_in_a": {
            "element_in_a_id": "some_id"
        }
    },
    "b": {
        "element_in_b": {
            "element_in_b_id": "some_id"
        }
    }
}
```

This dictionary was eventually changed to:

```
{
    "a": {
        "element_in_a": {
            "element_in_a_id": "some_id"
        },
        "optional_element_in_a": {
            "optional_element_in_a_id": "some_id"
        }
    },
    "b": {
        "element_in_b": {
            "element_in_b_id": "some_id"
        },
        "optional_element_in_b": {
            "optional_element_in_b_id": "some_id"
        }
    }
}
```

I have to modify the methods that access `element_in_a` or `element_in_b` of this dictionary such that, whenever `optional_element_in_a` exists in `a`, the methods must read only the optional elements **everywhere** (as a business rule, if the optional element exists in `a`, it also must exist in `b`), otherwise keep the old behaviour.

So far, as a quick solution, I've been adding these lines of code at the top of said methods

```
if "optional_element_in_a" in the_dict["a"]:
  element_key_a = "optional_element_in_a"
  element_key_b = "optional_element_in_b"
  id_key_a = "optional_element_in_a_id"
  id_key_b = "optional_element_in_b_id"
else:
  element_key_a = "element_in_a"
  element_key_b = "element_in_b"
  id_key_a = "element_in_a_id"
  id_key_b = "element_in_b_id"
```

and then read the elements using those keys I just defined.
This is obviously not a good solution, as I keep finding more and more methods needing this change.

I need to find the best pythonic way of having this logic in 1 place, so that all methods who need it can easily access it.

Btw, `the_dict` is **not** a class property/attribute. It is passed as argument to each method that operates on it, so I don't have access to it in `__init__`.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

```
if "optional_element_in_a" in the_dict["a"]:
  element_key_a = "optional_element_in_a"
  element_key_b = "optional_element_in_b"
  id_key_a = "optional_element_in_a_id"
  id_key_b = "optional_element_in_b_id"
else:
  element_key_a = "element_in_a"
  element_key_b = "element_in_b"
  id_key_a = "element_in_a_id"
  id_key_b = "element_in_b_id"
```

The main problem you have here is code repetition.

We can compress it by doing if on prefix, like such:

```
prefix = "optional_" if "optional_element_in_a" in the_dict["a"] else ""

element_key_a = prefix+"element_in_a"
element_key_b = prefix+"element_in_b"
id_key_a = prefix+"element_in_a_id"
id_key_b = prefix+"element_in_b_id"
```

Moreover, if you say "I've been adding these lines of code at the top of said methods", then it means even more repetition. And it's a sign you might need to define a function - either with this code above, some variation of it, or even something else.

Decide what you need: What is the structure of those keys you need? Do you need the key or the value? Do you need to extract always the same number of keys/values or different? Do you need to operate on the dict you have, or can you do a new dict with values you extracted (so that you don't care about whether the keys have "optional_" or not)?

Comment: Indeed, I'm looking for a solution to avoid repetition, either in the form of a helper function, as attributes of a helper class, or as any other format I'm not seeing.
I need to access values from this dict, based on keys that depend on the condition I explained above.
And copying the dict it is not ideal.

Comment: As I said, how you do this helper function depends on details. You can do as little as custom get-like function that gets optional if it's available (`def get_with_optional(my_dict, key): return my_dict.get("optional_"+key, my_dict[key])`) or a whole function like the if you had. It really depends whether you need only optionals, or sometimes optional and sometimes not...

Comment: I eventually went for a function that returns a named tuple, with the keys as members, defined inside the function depending on the argument. I posted it as answer.

Answer (score 0):

I eventually went with a function that returns a namedtuple, with the keys as members of that tuple.

Like this:

```
def get_keys(a_elem):
  has_optional_elem = "optional_element_in_a" in a_elem

  Keys = namedtuple("Keys", ["element_key_a", "element_key_b", ...])

  return Keys(
    element_key_a = "optional_element_in_a" if has_optional_elem else "element_in_a",
    element_key_b = "optional_element_in_b" if has_optional_elem else "element_in_b",
    ...
  )
```

so that then in each method that needs these keys I can do simply

```
keys = get_keys(the_dict[a])
the_needed_a_elem = the_dict[a][keys.element_key_a]
the_needed_b_elem = the_dict[b][keys.element_key_b]
...
```

which I believe is simple enough for good readability when using the keys.